# ngOnChange not called when value change

Tags: angular

I have setup [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/yqpluX?p=preview)

I am changing bool property of object on click of button and on  click `ngOnchange` should have triggered which is not happening. Why?. Is it related to same object reference is shared between parent and child component?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Angular change detection only checks object identity.
If you modify the content of an object, Angular won't recognize.
If if you have a binding to a property of an object or item of an array, Angular will check the binding thought, but `ngOnChanges` still won't be called.

This reason for this design is performance. Change detection would become much more of a performance burden if Angular would need to do deep object comparison.

A workaround is to copy the object or array, to create a new object with a different object id. Angular change detection will recognize it as change and update the binding to the child component.

```
  this.data.status = !this.data.status
  this.data = Object.assign({}, this.data);
```

or for array

```
  this.data = this.data.slice();
```

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/5EqoZHZ4cUfuY57tZylr?p=preview)

Other ways are implementing `DoCheck` in the child component and do the comparison yourself instead of depending on change detection.

Comment: IMO changing _"with a different object id"_ to _"with a different object reference"_ might be more technically correct but yours is easier to understand I guess sir :-)

Comment: @echonax thanks for pointing that out. I was thinking about what would be easier to understand and more accurate technically. I came to the conclusion that the memory address is actually the object id, and the reference would be a variable that points to that object. 2 different variables can be a reference to the same object, so object reference seemed misleading.